# Monitor does not switch off

Tags: monitors

I set the monitor to switch off after 14 minutes. But what happens is that it cycles between being off a second and backlight comes on another. I am sure that this is a Linux issue for the monitor does switches off after a set time in Windows 7.

I run Debian Jessie, 3.10-3-amd64, KDE 4.10.5. I use DVI for connection. Graphic card: Nvidia GeForce 7600gs, Monitor: Lenovo Thinkvision L220x. I don't use any screensaver.

Also, despite I use DVI, KDE system settings think that I use VGA (maybe this is normal):

[image]

This is how my power settings are:
[image]

Comment: Are you using a wireless mouse by any chance? It sounds like something is running and waking the screen up.

Comment: @terdon yes. a logitech performance mouse mx. strange that i dont have the issue in win7. maybe because of proprietary drivers for the mouse?

Comment: First make sure it's the mouse. Disconnect it and let the screen switch off. Does it still switch back on?

Comment: @terdon did that, does not affect. the monitor still cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the culprit was my graphics card ([asus](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/EN7600GS_SILENTHTD_Series/) geforce 7600gs) all along. I bought a geforce 210 and the problem is solved!

Comment: cool, nice to see that my suggestion worked. thanks for coming back and letting us know the result.